# Error converting tensorflow .pb model to .mlmodel

Tags: python, tensorflow, coreml, mlmodel

I am trying to convert a tensorflow graph (**.pb file**) into a **.mlmodel**

```py
import tfcoreml
coreml_model = tfcoreml.convert(tf_model_path='optimized_model.pb', mlmodel_path='FaceImages.mlmodel', output_feature_names=['final_result'], input_name_shape_dict={'ResizeBilinear': {'images': None, 'size': {None, None}}}, minimum_ios_deployment_target='13')
```

but I am getting following error:

> */usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/nnssa/frontend/tensorflow/graphdef_to_ssa.py
>   in load_tf_graph(graph_file)*
>
> ```
>  21     with tf.io.gfile.GFile(graph_file, "rb") as f:
>  22         graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
> ```
>
> ***`---> 23         graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())`***
>
> ```
>  24 
>  25     # Then, we import the graph_def into a new Graph and returns it
> ```
>
> **DecodeError: Error parsing message**

Could anybody help with this pls?

Here is the **colab project** where I have attached the tensorflow model and the associated code for conversion

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1S7nf7pnX15UuswFZaTih5pHhfDFwG5Xa

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the version of Tensorflow your are using is compatible with those libraries? This is just a guess, but you could try running

`!pip install tensorflow --upgrade`

at the top of the notebook to see if it resolves the issue.